# Thrift or RestKit for iOS Application

Tags: restkit, thrift

Can anybody provide some input whether we should use Apache Thrift OR RestKit(or something similar) to access/send the data from my iOS application to server and vice-versa. Any pros and cons of using one or the other.

Comment: Can anybody please help and provide useful input?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like you're trying to compare apples to oranges. Thrift and RestKit really have nothing to do with each other. If you want to use RestKit, you will need to use a backend services framework that allows you to easily create REST services for your iOS client to consume.

RestKit is an RESTful HTTP framework that allows you to send and retrieve data from an endpoint without manually managing the converting of data from one format to another. With RestKit you define relational mappings up front, then pull down data that RestKit -- using the mappings you've defined -- will then parse (generally JSON or XML format) and load into your objective-c objects.

More resources for you:

- [Difference between Thrift , JSON and REST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7467682/difference-between-thrift-json-and-rest)
- [Using Thrift for Objective-C](http://wiki.apache.org/thrift/ThriftUsageObjectiveC)
- [RestKit vs ASIHTTPRequest vs AFNetworking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8922296/is-restkit-a-good-replacement-for-asihttprequest)

Hope that helps.

Comment: I some what do not agree that Thrift (for iOS) and RestKit are apple and oranges. Because thrift can also use HTTP as transport layer (like RestKit), both can be used to get/post data from server. In other words both of these solutions can be used to perform GET/POST of data from the server for RESTFul web services and so on. As an example look at Evernote's cloud iOS API which is actually built on top of thrift as opposed to use RestKit, or AFNetworking, or any other framework: https://github.com/evernote/evernote-sdk-ios